# RSS Feed Empty in Firefox

Tags: rss, feed

I recently noticed that when accessing the RSS feeds for the blog I am currently working, no items appear in Firefox. If I look in Chrome, I see an unformatted xml file, but I don't seem to get anything in Firefox. I feel like I am probably missing something simple, but I can't figure out what it is.

Here is a link to the feed:
http://prettyaspie.com/category/ask/feed/

Has anyone seen similar behavior, or know what might cause this sort of error?

If there is any other information that might help, let me know, and I will get it.